# Lambda function to start and stop the instance when SSH service goes down

Tags: lambda

Need a lambda function which should start and stop the server when we are not able to SSH the server.
Please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Servers are going to unresponsive mode some times, so we need to do a manual stop and start the instance to bring it up. To automate this start and stop, i need a Python Lambda function which should take care of this whenever server goes offline.

Comment: How does a lambda function do that?

Comment: If we write a python script and place in customised functions, later configure cloudwatch to monitor the instance for every 5 min and if instance goes down make the lambda function to execute.

Comment: Cool, so what's stopping you from writing that? How much of that do you know how to write?

Comment: Sorry to say this.., first of all i am not sure how to write a python script and there is no option to do that using shell also, but our project requirement is that it should happen with python, so i was expecting some help here.

Comment: You need to go read how to write a python script and have a go yourself. Then you can come here with some code at least and we can help fill in the blanks for you. It's just that we're not a code writing service.

Comment: Sure... Will do so.

Comment: I managed to write a python script to Lambda function. 
Now let me tell you my requirement again.
When server goes to 1/2 check failed status a cloudwatch alarm will trigger a SNS notification which again triggers a Lambda function and server will be stooped and started again.

since we have more than 400 servers in our environment, i can not hardcode the instance id in my script, so i am picking the servers by their tag values. But here the problem is, whenever i get a notifiction from 1 server, all servers getting restarted which has same tag values.

Comment: Please don't add content to your question in the comments. Very few people will see it. If you want your question to hit the home page again you need to edit the question. You should copy your comment into the question so that the question doesn't get closed. You should read [ask] if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
import json
import time
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    ec2=boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
    instances =ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Env', 'Values': ['Prod']}])
    for ins in instances:
        print(ins.id)
        if ins.state['Name']!='stopped':
            ins.stop()
            print("Stopping the instance ")
            print(ins.id)
            while ins.state['Name']!='stopped':
                ins.reload()
                time.sleep(5)
                if ins.state['Name']=='stopped':
                    print("Instance "+ins.id+" is stopped now")
                    break

        if ins.state['Name']!='running':
            ins.start()
            print("Starting the instance "+ins.id)
            while ins.state['Name']!='running':
                ins.reload()
                time.sleep(5)
                if ins.state['Name']=='running':
                    print("Instance "+ins.id+" is running now")
                    break
```

Comment: Is this an answer or should this be in the question? If it should be in the question then you should edit your question, add the code, and then delete this answer.